# How to convert boolean to int in my DataTble?

Tags: c#, datatable, int, boolean

this is my code:

```
 DataTable dt = DALlayer.GetDWHVoyagesByDate(FromDate, ToDate);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Boolean FloatTypes = Convert.ToBoolean( dt.Rows[i]["FloatTypes"]);

                dt.Rows[i]["FloatTypes"] = FloatTypes ? 3 : 2;
            }
```

I want to convert boolean to int

but my result is true instead of 3 or 2

Comment: Going from boolean to int will give an int not a true or false?  Your question is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng storing and int value into a datatable column which is of type boolean will show you a boolean value. A boolean is just an int where false is 0 and anything else is true. That is what the OP is doing

Comment: The OP doesn't understand that.